# Adsense not working for subdomain, 403 error

Tags: adsense

Ive added Site ziomalum.pl, and also subdomain forum.ziomalum.pl with auto ads off.
Ads are working only for main domain ( https://ziomalum.pl ), in https://forum.ziomalum.pl in console I see 403 errors, why ?

Thanks for help

[image]

Comment: It takes some time before you start seeing ads. Or, your ad code could be wrong.

Comment: code wrong ? how if it works for main domain ? about time.. well Ive added in sites main domain with subdomain same day. So rather not the issue.